# Unified connectors for DataStream/Table APIs

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

I am writing a simple connector (source/sink) for Flink 1.14.4 which mostly wraps the official Kafka Connector and automatically set ups custom serializers/deserializers. I'm a bit confused about the current state of the new source/sink interfaces introduced in [FLIP-27](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/x/co_zBQ) and [FLIP-143](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/x/KEJ4CQ). Is it currently possible to write unified connectors, really (that is, connectors that work across different APIs, such as DataStream/Table)? By looking at the code of the current Kafka Connector, I see it comes with both legacy and new flavours, but AFAIK the connector for the Table API still relies on the legacy API only. Also, by reading the official documentation:

- https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/dev/table/sourcessinks/

It seems that the new interfaces cannot still be used for the Table API. To make it worse, I find it very confusing that only sources are mentioned in the DataStream section, which already describes the new approach:

- https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/dev/datastream/sources/

but nothing is said regarding sinks. Overall, I think this leaves the user not knowing very well how to approach the creation of custom connectors as of today. In particular, I would expect having an equivalent section for the DataStream API, i.e., one covering the creation of user-defined sources & sinks, as that given above for the Table API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Unified Source and Sink API (FLIP-27 and FLIP-143) were created to create one interface for connectors so they could be used for both bounded (batch) and unbounded (stream) data.

Both interfaces allow for building a source/sink that you can use in either DataStream or Table/SQL API. That's currently already the case for FileSystem, Kafka and Pulsar (as of Flink 1.15 which will be released shortly).

You're absolutely right that the current documentation doesn't make this clear. At the moment, the Flink community is working on externalizing the connectors (moving each of them from the Flink repository to their own individual repository) and overhauling the documentation and guides on how to write a connector.

Comment: Many thanks Martijn! Can you point me to the official tickets/roadmap?